# Error when trying to add subdomain or add databases with cPanel

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel

cPanel is throwing up an error everytime I try to add or edit an existing subdomain. The same error is showing up when I try to add a new database.

`Cpanel::AdminBin::_get_cpwrapd_connection could not connect to /usr/local/cpanel/var/cpwrapd.sock`

PHPMyAdmin, FTP and SSH are all working perfectly, so the problem is something to do with cPanel. The server is a VPS with GoDaddy. I was installing a program running on Ruby 1.8.7, and this error started showing up after I installed the program. I have tried `/scripts/installruby` but that's giving me this error:

```
The internal error was:

    (RegexpError) Stack overflow in regexp matcher: /.*((?>\/\*.*?\*\/\s+))
                         ([\w\.\s]+\s* = \s+)?rb_define_(class|module).*?"(Mongrel)"/mx

ERROR:  While generating documentation for mongrel-1.1.5
... MESSAGE:   Stack overflow in regexp matcher: /.*((?>\/\*.*?\*\/\s+))
                         ([\w\.\s]+\s* = \s+)?rb_define_(class|module).*?"(Mongrel)"/mx
... RDOC args: --ri --op /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/doc/mongrel-1.1.5/ri --line-numbers --title Mongrel --main README lib ext CHANGELOG COPYING lib/mongrel/camping.rb lib/mongrel/cgi.rb lib/mongrel/command.rb lib/mongrel/configurator.rb lib/mongrel/const.rb lib/mongrel/debug.rb lib/mongrel/gems.rb lib/mongrel/handlers.rb lib/mongrel/header_out.rb lib/mongrel/http_request.rb lib/mongrel/http_response.rb lib/mongrel/init.rb lib/mongrel/rails.rb lib/mongrel/stats.rb lib/mongrel/tcphack.rb lib/mongrel/uri_classifier.rb lib/mongrel.rb LICENSE README --title mongrel-1.1.5 Documentation --quiet
die [installruby] Failed command: /usr/bin/gem install mongrel-1.1.5.gem --local
exit level [die] [pid=5273] (Failed command: /usr/bin/gem install mongrel-1.1.5.gem --local)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by rebooting cPanel, using `/etc/init.d/cpanel restart`